Can the constraint $x + y \ge y{e^{\frac{{{e^t}}}{y}}}$ be presented as an exponential cone constraint?
I am a network engineer who is currently working with some exponential cone optimization. For my application the exponential cone constraint $x + y \ge y{e^{\frac{t}{y}}}$ work quite well through the YALMIP modeling language since the right hand side is a perspective function.
Out of pure curiosity, I tweak this constraint a little bit and turn it into $x + y \ge y{e^{\frac{{{e^t}}}{y}}}$. At this point the 3D plot of this inequality constraint on the positive orthant still look pretty much convex (by my own inspection). However, I do not know how to mathematically turn $x + y \ge y{e^{\frac{{{e^t}}}{y}}}$ into an exponential cone constraint.
Therefore, my question is "Can the constraint $x + y \ge y{e^{\frac{{{e^t}}}{y}}}$ be presented as an exponential cone constraint ?"
Would you kindly help me with this ?
Thank you for your enthusiasm

By composition since exp is increasing and $y\geq 0$ is forced, $x+y\geq ye^{\frac{e^t}{y}}$ is the same as $x+y\geq ye^{\frac{u}{y}}$ and $u\geq e^t$, both of which are expcone-representable.

Oh so that is how it is. Can you formalize it into an official answer so that I could accept it
